# cakephp debug function result 'date' => 'The provided value is invalid'

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I wanna save some data in my database on cakephp 
here is my template...

```
echo $this->Form->create();

echo $this->Form->input('outtime',
    array(
        'class' => 'outtime',
        'id' => 'outtime',
        'name' => 'outtime'
    )
);

echo $this->Form->input('out date',
    array(
        'class' => 'datepicker0',
        'id' => 'outdate',
        'name' => 'outdate'
    )
);

echo $this->Form->input('return date',
    array(
        'class' => 'datepicker0',
        'id' => 'returndate',
        'name' => 'returndate'
    )
);

echo $this->Form->button(__('submit'));

echo $this->Form->end();
```

and this is my database template.

when I used save function it did not work i used debug function on my code ...

```
  if ($this->Outs->save($out)) {
               $this->Flash->success(__('The out has been saved.'));
        } else {
                debug($out->errors()); die;
                $this->Flash->error(__('The out could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

        }
```

when i run it result is

[image: error]
 my full method code ...
 public function addout()

```
{
    $uid = $this->Auth->User()['id'];

    $out = $this->Outs->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $out = $this->Outs->patchEntity($out, $this->request->data);

        $this->request->data['user_id'] = $uid;

    }
        if ($this->Outs->save($out)) {
               $this->Flash->success(__('The out has been saved.'));
        } else {
                debug($this->request->data); exit;
                $this->Flash->error(__('The out could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

        }
}
```

my debug out put is...
[debug out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Wt3.png)
 I hope this informations help you.
I don`t know any thing about this error please help me

Comment: You have space on two inputs ```out date``` and ```return date```,  also CakePHP Form Helper automagically set fields attributes : name and id, so don't add manualy if you don't known what you doing.  On controller before calling save method, try ```debug($this->request-data); exit;```

Comment: I checked every thing and my posted data was correct  can you guide me some more?

Comment: Add debug output and full controller method to your question.